# Best choice to represent video for iOS and Android

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, java-native-interface

I am developing an app for iOS and Android to make a video call between two devices. The idea is to develop one c++ library for both platforms, and to integrate the comunication and display parts in the same way.
For compatibility reasons, I am using OpenGL to represent the video, and FFMPEG to encode the comunication, but in some other questions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666513/what-is-the-best-method-to-render-video-frames)) I have read that it is not the best option for Android. Although, I have realized that on iOS, the opengl approach is faster than the native approach I have tested.
So the question is: For Android, which is the alternative to OpenGL, but using JNI? Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenGL ES, a flavor of the OpenGL specification intended for embedded devices. This version is also optimized for mobile devices. OpenGL ES is available for Android and iOS.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html
- https://developer.apple.com/opengl-es/

The following SO questions can get you in the right direction when it comes to implementing this:

- [Android Video Player Using NDK, OpenGL ES, and FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676178/android-video-player-using-ndk-opengl-es-and-ffmpeg)
- [Android. How play video on Surface(OpenGL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375598/android-how-play-video-on-surfaceopengl)
- [OpenGL in Android for video display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315966/opengl-in-android-for-video-display)
- [play video using opengles, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006094/play-video-using-opengles-android)
- [opengl es(iphone) render from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738110/opengl-esiphone-render-from-file)
- https://discussions.apple.com/message/7661759#7661759